# Stumped at why my imageviews are blinking

Tags: java, android, animation, timer

I have set up two rows of horizontally sliding animations of four imageviews, the top images sliding to the right, the bottom sliding to the left, I'm curious to know why my images blink wildly as they animated, I'd appreceiate any insight from anyone who has an idea, Thanks!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Display mainDisplay;
ViewGroup mainLayout;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutPositioner;
RelativeLayout tsubslayout;
Context ourContext;
ImageView subone_Iv, subtwo_Iv, subthree_Iv, subfour_Iv, blur_Iv, pickup_Iv, delivery_Iv, logo_Iv;
TimerTask thisTimerTask;
Timer thisTimer;

float offsetX = 0.0f;
float offsetY = 0.0f;

float subonexpos = -1440;
float suboneypos = 0;

float subtwoxpos = 0;
float subtwoypos = 0;

float subthreexpos = 0;
float subthreeypos = 1280;

float subfourxpos = 1440;
float subfourypos = 1280;

float imgPosOne = 1;
float imgPosTwo = 1;

float timerUntilTitleScreen = 500;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//Remove title bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);//Hides notification bar
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//set content view AFTER ABOVE sequence (to avoid crash)

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    mainDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    mainLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.id_layout);

    DisplayMetrics m = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(m);
    int windowHeight = m.heightPixels;
    int windowWidth = m.widthPixels;

    offsetX = (windowWidth / 1440.0f);
    offsetY = (windowHeight / 2560.0f);

    ourContext = this;

    transitioningImages();

    logo_Iv = new ImageView(this);
    SetImgPos(0, 0, 1440, 2560, logo_Iv);
    logo_Iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
    logo_Iv.setLayoutParams(layoutPositioner);
    mainLayout.addView(logo_Iv);

    thisTimerTask = new ThisClass();
    thisTimer = new Timer();
    thisTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(thisTimerTask, 16, 16);

  }

void transitioningImages()
{

    subone_Iv = new ImageView(this);
    SetImgPos(subonexpos, suboneypos, 1440, 1280, subone_Iv);
    subone_Iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    subone_Iv.setLayoutParams(layoutPositioner);
    mainLayout.addView(subone_Iv);

    subtwo_Iv = new ImageView(this);
    SetImgPos(subtwoxpos, subtwoypos, 1440, 1280, subtwo_Iv);
    subtwo_Iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    subtwo_Iv.setLayoutParams(layoutPositioner);
    mainLayout.addView(subtwo_Iv);

    subthree_Iv = new ImageView(this);
    SetImgPos(subthreexpos, subthreeypos, 1440, 1280, subthree_Iv);
    subthree_Iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    subthree_Iv.setLayoutParams(layoutPositioner);
    mainLayout.addView(subthree_Iv);

    subfour_Iv = new ImageView(this);
    SetImgPos(subfourxpos, subfourypos, 1440, 1280, subfour_Iv);
    subfour_Iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    subfour_Iv.setLayoutParams(layoutPositioner);
    mainLayout.addView(subfour_Iv);

}

void imgAppearanceUpdate()
{
    if(imgPosOne == 1)
    {
        subone_Iv.setBackgroundColor(0xff8A2BE2); //purple
        subtwo_Iv.setBackgroundColor(0xff7FFF00); //lime green
    }

    else if(imgPosOne == 2)
    {
        subone_Iv.setBackgroundColor(0xff7FFF00); //lime green
        subtwo_Iv.setBackgroundColor(0xff8A2BE2); //purple
    }


    if(imgPosTwo == 1)
    {
        subthree_Iv.setBackgroundColor(0xffFF8C00); //orange
        subfour_Iv.setBackgroundColor(0xff00BFFF); //aquablue
    }

    else if(imgPosTwo == 2)
    {
        subthree_Iv.setBackgroundColor(0xff00BFFF); //aquablue
        subfour_Iv.setBackgroundColor(0xffFF8C00); //orange
    }


}

void imgPosUpdate() {

    if (subonexpos < 0) {
        subonexpos += 6;
        subtwoxpos += 6;

        SetImgPos(subonexpos, suboneypos, 1440, 1280, subone_Iv);
        subone_Iv.setLayoutParams(layoutPositioner);

        SetImgPos(subtwoxpos, subtwoypos, 1440, 1280, subtwo_Iv);
        subtwo_Iv.setLayoutParams(layoutPositioner);
    }

    else if (subonexpos == 0) {
        imgPosOne += 1;
        if (imgPosOne == 3) {
            imgPosOne = 1;
        }

        subonexpos = -1440;
        subtwoxpos = 0;

        SetImgPos(subonexpos, suboneypos, 1440, 1280, subone_Iv);
        subone_Iv.setLayoutParams(layoutPositioner);

        SetImgPos(subtwoxpos, subtwoypos, 1440, 1280, subtwo_Iv);
        subtwo_Iv.setLayoutParams(layoutPositioner);
    }



    if (subthreexpos > -1440) {
        subthreexpos -= 6;
        subfourxpos -= 6;

        SetImgPos(subthreexpos, subthreeypos, 1440, 1280, subthree_Iv);
        subthree_Iv.setLayoutParams(layoutPositioner);

        SetImgPos(subfourxpos, subfourypos, 1440, 1280, subfour_Iv);
        subfour_Iv.setLayoutParams(layoutPositioner);
    }

    else if (subthreexpos == -1440) {
        imgPosTwo += 1;
        if (imgPosTwo == 3) {
            imgPosTwo = 1;
        }

        subthreexpos = 0;
        subfourxpos = 1440;

        SetImgPos(subthreexpos, subthreeypos, 1440, 1280, subthree_Iv);
        subthree_Iv.setLayoutParams(layoutPositioner);

        SetImgPos(subfourxpos, subfourypos, 1440, 1280, subfour_Iv);
        subfour_Iv.setLayoutParams(layoutPositioner);
    }



}

class ThisClass extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (timerUntilTitleScreen > 0)
                {timerUntilTitleScreen -= 2;}



                if (timerUntilTitleScreen < 20) {
                    logo_Iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    delivery_Iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    pickup_Iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    subone_Iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    subtwo_Iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    subthree_Iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    subfour_Iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    imgPosUpdate();
                    imgAppearanceUpdate(); //swapping images when they go off screen
                }



            }
        });
    }
}

public void SetImgPos(float x, float y, float width, float height, ImageView theView) {
    layoutPositioner = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // offsetY/offsetX is the difference in ratio of the current screen
    int y_Margin = (int) (offsetY * y); //changes the y position coordinates to adjust to the ratio of the current screen it is being seen on
    int x_Margin = (int) (offsetX * x); //changes the x position coordinates to adjust to the ratio of the current screen it is being seen on

    layoutPositioner.topMargin = y_Margin; //adjusts where the image's margin begins
    layoutPositioner.leftMargin = x_Margin; //adjusts where the image's margin begins

    layoutPositioner.bottomMargin = (int) offsetY - (y_Margin - theView.getHeight()); //adjusts where the image's margin ends
    layoutPositioner.rightMargin = (int) offsetX - (x_Margin - theView.getWidth()); //adjusts where the image's margin ends

    layoutPositioner.width = (int) (width * offsetX); //adjust the image/layout size to the ratio of the current screen its being seen on
    layoutPositioner.height = (int) (height * offsetY);

}
```

}

Comment: Without looking at your code: are you using double-buffering?

Comment: I'm not familiar with doublebuffering

Comment: after a quick google search i'm assuming your suggesting it might offset the flickering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumbled upon the solution, in my SetImgPos function ...

```
layoutPositioner.bottomMargin = (int) offsetY - (y_Margin - theView.getHeight()); 
layoutPositioner.rightMargin = (int) offsetX - (x_Margin - theView.getWidth());
```

was apparently too much for my app too handle and changing it to ...

```
layoutPositioner.bottomMargin = (int) offsetY - (int) (y_Margin - height); 
layoutPositioner.rightMargin = (int) offsetX - (int) (x_Margin - width);
```

removed the blinking